# java springboot validate request parameters springboot @Valid annotation is invalid

Tags: java, spring

Adding @NotBlank annotation to member variables in DTO does not take effect. What is the reason? Please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is too little information here. Make sure you have the `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency and not the individual api and validator implementation. Also make sure you haven't used `hibernate-validator` 7 or up as that isn't compatible (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check this dependency is present in the pom.xml file. If it doesn't present then add.
With dependency present in your project now use can use @NotBlack and @Valid annotation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId> 
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.197</version> 
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

For more information about [Validation in Spring Boot check this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from including spring-boot-starter-validation in dependency, you must include **@Valid** annotation on @RequestBody in the controller for @NotBlank annotation to apply on member variables in DTO .